# cygwin 1.7.15 handling of "set -e" in shell scripts (error in sub-shell causes parent to exit)

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am using this:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 bassoon 1.7.15(0.260/5/3) 2012-05-09 10:25 i686 Cygwin
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
$ cat myexpr.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "In myexpr, Before  expr"
ac_optarg=`expr x--with-gnu-as : 'x[^=]*=\(.*\)'`
echo "ac_optarg=$ac_optarg"
echo "In myexpr, After  expr"

$ cat myexpr2.sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

echo "In myexpr, Before  expr"
ac_optarg=`expr x--with-gnu-as : 'x[^=]*=\(.*\)'`
echo "ac_optarg=$ac_optarg"
echo "In myexpr, After  expr"
```

The only difference between the two scripts is that myexpr2.sh uses "set -e"

```
$ echo $$
2880
$ ./myexpr.sh
In myexpr, Before  expr
ac_optarg=
In myexpr, After  expr
$ ./myexpr2.sh
In myexpr, Before  expr
```

Expected behavior, so far.

If I do this in the parent shell (PID 2880, above):

```
$ set -e
$ ./myexpr.sh
```

The parent shell exits! That is pID 2880 above where I did the "set -e"

This is not the behavior on Linux or cygwin 1.5.12. Is this a bug in cygwin or BASH on cygwin?

Comment: The expected behavior is for `ac_optarg` to have a null value? I think there's a problem with your `expr` command, which makes `set -e` abort the second script.

Comment: Hi, yes, the expected behavior is that ac_optarg will be null since the regexp will not succeed. The behavior that is unusual is the parent shell exiting when I "set -e" in the parent shell. If I "set -e" in the parent shell and execute myexpr.sh (I also added exit 0 to the last line just to be safe), the parent shell exits. Only on cygwin 1.7.15

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it's a feature of the Bash environment. This happens when you don't have the Bash shell environment variable ***execfail*** set, and/or the Shell environment variable ***errexit***.

> ```
> execfail - (is a BASHOPTS)
>
> If set, a non-interactive shell will not exit if it cannot execute 
> the file specified as an argument to the exec builtin command. 
> An interactive shell does not exit if exec fails.
>
> errexit -  (is a SHELLOPTS)
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a 
> single simple command (see Simple Commands), a subshell command enclosed 
> in parentheses (see Command Grouping), or one of the commands executed as 
> part of a command list enclosed by braces (see Command Grouping) returns a 
> non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part 
> of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part 
> of the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a && or || 
> list except the command following the final && or ||, any command in a 
> pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status is being inverted 
> with !. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.
>
> This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment 
> separately (see Command Execution Environment), and may cause subshells to 
> exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.
> ```

Different Linux versions have different defaults for these. 
You can check which are **enabled** with:

```
echo "SHELLOPTS=$SHELLOPTS"
echo "BASHOPTS=$BASHOPTS"
```

and you can see all of them using:

```
set -o && echo -e "\n" && shopt -p
```

So, you need to enable yours with:

```
shopt -s execfail
```

If that doesn't work, you may also have to unset (off) the **errexit** of $SHELLOPTS with:

```
set -o errexit
```

For further info, see: [The GNU Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/)!

PS. "set" is using reverse logic so if you wanna use the 'e' flag you have to use a "+": `set +e`